# Problema em realizar a soma das linhas de uma matriz bidimensional C++

Tags: c++, matriz

## include

## include

using namespace std;
int main()
{

```
srand(time(0));
int bid[3][3];
int impar = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)  
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        bid[x][y] = rand() % (386 - 0 + 1) + (-112);
    }
}
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)  
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {
        cout << bid[a][b] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
// PARTE DA SOMA DAS LINHAS 

int vetor[3];
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
        vetor[0] += bid[j][0]﻿;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    vetor[1] += bid[j][1]﻿;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    vetor[2] += bid[j][2]﻿;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "A soma das colunas eh: " << vetor[i];
}


system("pause");
```

}

O código funciona até a parte de criar uma matriz unidimensional pra receber a soma das linhas, e gera os erros C2146 e C2065, já tentei de tudo pra compilar e sem sucesso

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de você dizer isso

> O código funciona até a parte de criar uma matriz unidimensional pra

na verdade seu código **não** funcionou, já que ocorreram erros de compilação.

Copiei o código que você postou e abri no vim, olhe o que apareceu:

```
// PARTE DA SOMA DAS LINHAS 

int vetor[3];
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    vetor[0] += bid[j][0]<feff>;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    vetor[1] += bid[j][1]<feff>;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    vetor[2] += bid[j][2]<feff>;
}
```

Em outras palavras, tem lixo no final dessas linha com "feff". Provavelmente você colou partes de um outro fonte que estava em UTF-8.

Solução é simples: reescreva o final dessas linhas.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, sou novo no meio e não consegui compreender sua resposta, poderia me explicar oq seria  UTF-8 e qual parte eu precisaria reescrever ?

Comment: apague as linhas onde eu marquei feff, e as redigite novamente, isso provavelmente vai resolver o problema

Answer (score 0):

Para somar as colunas utilize a mesma estrutura que usou para a leitura:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    vetor[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            vetor[i] += bid[j][i]﻿;
    }
    cout << "A soma da coluna: " << i << " eh: " << vetor[i];
}
```